# What to set as default when the type is A (Scala)

Tags: scala, design-patterns, pattern-matching, matching, tail-recursion

I have an exercise in Scala in which I have to transform that kind of list (a,a,a,b,c,d,d,e,a,a) into
((a,3),(b,1),(c,1),(d,2),(e,1),(a,2)).
I obviously know that my algorithm is not correct yet, but I wanted to start with anything.
The problem is that I don't know how to turn on the function (last line), because the error is that whatever I take as previous' argument, it says that required: A, found: Int/String etc.
The previous was meant to be as a head of the previous iteration.

```
def compress[A](l: List[A]): List[(A, Int)] = {
  def compressHelper(l: List[A], acc: List[(A, Int)], previous: A, counter: Int): List[(A, Int)] = {
    l match {
      case head::tail => {
        if (head == previous) {
          compressHelper(tail, acc :+ (head, counter+1), head, counter+1)
        }
        else {
          compressHelper(tail, acc :+ (head, counter), head, 1)
        }
      }
      case Nil => acc
    }
  }
  compressHelper(l, List(), , 1)
}
```

Comment: You can't, especially because you won't always have a previous element, use `Option[A]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need  to pass `previous` explicitly, just look at the accumulator:

```
def compress[A](l: List[A], acc: List[(A, Int)]=Nil): List[(A, Int)] =
   (l, acc) match {
       case (Nil, _) => acc.reverse
       case (head :: tail, (a, n) :: rest) if a == head =>
            compress(tail, (a, n+1) :: rest)
       case (head :: tail, _) => compress (tail, (head, 1) :: acc)
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch. Required: List[(A, Int)], found: Iterable[(A, Int)] 
I get this kind of error when trying to compile this. It's about this acc.reversed

Comment: ok, my bad, it's just about acc.reverse, not reversed :) thank you.
I've got a question - you use (a, n) :: rest, because the list is like that List((a,b)). So if for example I had a list which was like List((a,b,c,d), (e,f,g,h)) I'd have to write (a,b,c,d):: rest instead of head :: tail? So using head :: tail is only for situation, when in list there are single elements?

Comment: @squall `head::tail` deconstructs the list into first element and the rest. If list contained tuples, then the value of `head` would end up being a tuple (like `(a,b,c,d)` or whatever). You can still do `head::tail` if you don't care about individual elements of the tuple, and just want the whole thing. Or you can further deconstruct it like `(a, _, c, _) :: tail`. You can nest these unapplies as much as needed ... `case (Some((a,b,c))::_, (x :: y :: z :: _), _)::tail => ...`